# How to understand the concept of scope in Antlr

Tags: scope, antlr

I can easily understand @members. It add members to the parser class. But what does scope mean?

```
scope Symbols{
    Set types;
}
```

Is "Symbols" a member in parser class? I check the generated java file,

```
protected static class Symbols_scope {
    Set types;
}
protected Stack Symbols_stack = new Stack();
```

The scope becomes an inner class and a Stack member.
And When I use Symbols::types in rule action, I see this in java file,

```
Symbols_stack.push(new Symbols_scope());
int translation_unit_StartIndex = input.index();
((Symbols_scope)Symbols_stack.peek()).types = new HashSet();
```

So, every time I refer to "symbol", it create a new instance of "Symbol" and push it into the stack?
And there are global and local scopes. What is the difference? In the java file they both generate an inner class and a Stack member. Then what make "global scope" global and make "local scope" local?